# Textview displaying "Hello World" instead of text set

Tags: android, android-listview

I am having a listview. Initially I get such row item.

[image]
But when I scroll down, then at some positions I get this,
[image]

I am not getting why this is happening.  Here I am using TreeObserver to get width of firsttext view, so as to get the length of string displayed in firsttextview and display the rest in other.

Here is the code for this, I have two layouts inflated, I am posting code for this one.

```
 if(type==0){

            if(convertView==null){

                convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.incoming_msg_row,parent, false);
                holder=new ViewHolder();
                holder.messageFirstPart = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.messageFirstPart);
                holder.messageLeftPart = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.messageLeftPart);

                holder.username= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SendersName);

                holder.time=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
                holder.leftline=convertView.findViewById(R.id.leftline);
                holder.rightline=convertView.findViewById(R.id.rightline);

                holder.view3=convertView.findViewById(R.id.incoming_msg_row_innerlayout);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            }
            else    
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            holder.messageFirstPart.setText(message[position]);
                holder.username.setText("John");
                holder.time.setText(timestamp[position]);


        RelativeLayout mineLayout= 
              (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.incoming_msg_row_innerlayout);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=(LayoutParams) mineLayout.getLayoutParams();

                for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){

                System.out.println(x[i]);
                if(position==x[i]){
                    holder.time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.leftline.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.rightline.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    params.topMargin=20;
    //                      holder.view3.requestLayout();
                    mineLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

                    break;
                }
                else{

                    holder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.leftline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.rightline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   //                       params.topMargin+=0;
   //                       holder.view3.requestLayout();
                    params.topMargin=90;
                    mineLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

                }
            }

            if(position==0){
                holder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.leftline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.rightline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                params.topMargin=90;
                mineLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
            }

                holder.messageFirstPart.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                        new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                            @Override
                            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                width = holder.messageFirstPart.getWidth();
                                int totalCharstoFit;

                                String chat = holder.messageFirstPart.getText().toString();

                                String substring=null,substringtwo=null;
                                totalCharstoFit =  

                          holder.messageFirstPart.getPaint().breakText(chat, 0,
                                            chat.length(), true, width, null);
                                            substring = chat.substring(0, totalCharstoFit);
                                            substringtwo = chat.substring(substring.length(),
                                                    chat.length());

                                            holder.messageFirstPart.setText(chat);
                                            holder.messageLeftPart.setText(substringtwo);


                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                    holder.messageFirstPart.getViewTreeObserver()
                                            .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                                } else {
                                    holder.messageFirstPart.getViewTreeObserver()
                                            .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                                }

                            }
                        }); 

            }
```

Comment: check does that Textview having any default text set in its layout?

Comment: can we see your xml file?

Comment: yaa.. there default text is HEllo world.. bt removing it.. makes text view null at those postions where hello world was coming.

Comment: @HarishVats see below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hello world is a constant text defined somewhere in strings or in xml for the textview.
 Check in xml that whether you have given. android:text="Hello world" or you mentioned in strings.xml and used that in textview. android:text="@string/hello" if you mentioned that in strings.

Comment: I know... Hello World is coming from there...But Why only at some positions??

Answer (score 1):

`Hello world` is usually a sort of "default text" you get after you created a new project and, probably, when you create your `ListView`'s row, in the xml, you left the `android:text` field set with that string, and because of the recycling system of the ListView you are getting the default text. you have probably forget to set the text for that `TextView`

Comment: I have set the Text.. that's why Its getting displayed initially..
Hello World comes on few positions after scrolling down

Comment: I think that the big `if(type==0){` could be a problem.

Comment: that is for checking the type I want to inflate. Its not the problem

Comment: actually it does since you are setting the text only it type is zero

Comment: No Its not the issue.. type==0 is for this layout.. I have two layouts,thats why I am checking type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define adapter like this;

```
 ListView lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv);
                lv.refreshDrawableState();
                AdapterClass adapter = new AdapterClass (context, R.layout.row, adpArray);

                try {
                    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

                lv.invalidate();
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                lv.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

> yaa.. there default text is HEllo world.. bt removing it.. makes text
>   view null at those postions where hello world was coming.

Ok. So i guess it might be due to "substringtwo" object returning null. Can you try moving

`holder.messageLeftPart.setText(substringtwo);`

into below if block

```
//Check for not string object null and non empty and not containing string value null
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(substringtwo) && !substringtwo.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
    //set message text here
}
```

OR

try initializing variable substringtwo to empty string i.e. `String substringtwo = "";`